# Diagnose poor performance / EC2 to RDS (different avail zones)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have 3 EC2 instances and 3 RDS instances - each EC2 instance uses an RDS instance that is in the same availability zone as it's primary database.

The rds instances all have the same sort of data and database/table structures.

One of the tables holds configuration data that is (on demand) exported to JSON and used by web applications.

I have a PHP program that edits this configuration parameter table on it's associated local database.
I recently added code so that when edits are saved they are written to all three databases.  These are just simple table updates.  The code opens the first database - updates the affected rows, closes the database, opens the second database, updates it's affected rows etc etc.

Updating the local RDS instance takes around **700 milliseconds** to complete. 
Updating either of the remote RDS instances takes **nearly a minute each**.

I am using the RDS instance endpoint as the server name when updating.

I'm at a loss as to how to begin to troubleshoot the problem.
Suggestions / recommendations would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the local process already updated the rows when it created the update script.

Comment: Please clarify this statement: "RDS instance that is in the same availability zone as it's primary database."  And what do you mean by "local" and "remote"?  Same vs. different availability zones as the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question. So, are these three set-ups ( EC2 + RDS ) in different geographical locations all-together OR just different availability zones in same location ? Basic question is if on local setup it takes less than a second; why it is taking 1 min to update remote setup.

I will recommend you to start with doing a ping request from each EC2 to instance to other EC2 instances and note the time interval and packet losses. This will give you a fair idea of network latency.

Also you can use Unix tool MTR for monitoring network between different servers.

Comment: @RoyHB What was the output of things I mentioned in this answer ?

Comment: ["sydney"=>array("EC2","RDS"), "singapore"=>array("EC2","RDS"),"tokyo"=array("EC2","RDS")];

Comment: I just woke up (04:20) and am now going to try your suggestions Deepak - :-)

Comment: Got it :)  .. If network latency is very high; create a customer support ticket.. AWS should fix it. It is possible that only one of these location has some problem.  Another thing should be to ping on all these locations from a fourth location probably from your laptop.

Comment: Very interesting.  I can ping sydney RDS from either Sydney or Singapore EC2, but I cannot ping Singapore RDS from either Singapore or Sydney.  Both RDS instances are set to an EC2 security group that is identical in each region and allows all ICMP.  I can connect from Sydney EC2 to Singapore RDS using mysql command line.  I need to spend some time to make sure I haven't done something stupid before calling in the Amazon Cavalry.  Thanks for your suggestion about checking low level connectivity Deepak - I hadn't thought of that - I was thinking the problem was at a higher level.

Comment: AWS does restrict Ping traffic in some cases. Try using MTR.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22243/discussion-between-royhb-and-deepak)